# What do you call the techniques of drawing characters like this to hide violence in comics?

Tags: comics

[image]

What do you call the techniques of drawing characters like this to hide violence in comics? I saw it several times, but I don't know if there's a name for this technique and if it's used in other situation other than to hide gore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Those are called [Silhouettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette)

Silhouette is the technique of showing nothing but the outline of a character.  It's commonly used for [dramatic effect](https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0199.html), or to conceal the identity of a character who hasn't yet been introduced properly (frequently for dramatic effect).

One of the common recommendations when designing a comic or cartoon is that all of your main characters should be identifiable by their silhouette alone.  For example, I imagine you can identify many of the characters in the image you posted.